# jQuery: Insert html from "title" tag into a "span" of a H2 tag

Tags: jquery, insert, title, html

Say I had the following HTML:

```
<h2>Heading <span></span></h2>

<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="I am wanting to be in H2!">Something</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="I too am wanting to be in H2!">Something else</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to take the title tag from the  and place it inside the span of the h2. How can I do so?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('h2 span').html( $(this).attr('title') );
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Paul - I can get this to work if there is no other HTML in the page, but trying it in my actual page, it is not working... Maybe because it's conflicting with something else or I'm not targetting the classes properly. I don't know but thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you have more h2s with spans?

Comment: Some error somewhere else in my code. But this works, so tick!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function(){
  $("h2 span").append($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad, but I want to display the title in the span of the h2 when the a is clicked. I tried changing the 'each' to 'click' but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @lorenzium: Please reflect this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h2 span').html($('title').html());
```

should work :)

i recommend giving the span an unique id, so to call `$('#id').ht....` instead

Comment: It seems that the OP does not mean the `title` tag but the title **attribute** of an `a` tag.